# Add Tomcat 9 to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have downloaded and installed tomcat 9 to my machine, but on Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment, after clicking on Add, I see only Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8, but not Tomcat 9.

What I have done:
1) installed tomcat 9 to local server;
2) updated eclipse to Mars (latest as of 2015-11-25);
3) installed eclipse "JST Server Adapters" and "JST Server Adapters Extensions"

Note:
My purpose of using tomcat 9 is it seems to be the only version that explicitly support java 8 and later, and my web app is using java 8. (http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)
I also have tomcat 7 exist in project but I also want to keep it in the machine, not to delete it.

Please see screenshot.

[image]

Please let me know about any config that I missed!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two things to note here:

- **Tomcat 9 is not released yet.** Not a final version that is. If you check the official [website](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi), you will see that the only available version is an M1 version. Hence there is no support from Eclipse WTP for this early version. It will come soon, but not yet.
- **Tomcat 9 is not the only version that explicitly supports Java 8.** If you check this [page](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), you will see that *"Supports Java version: 8 and later"*, which in this context means, that it officially support only Java 8 and above. It does *not* mean however this is the only one supporting Java 8. Theoretically you should be able to use any Tomcat version, in practice a **Tomcat 8 will work perfectly well**, since it support Java 7 and above. The majority of people with a Java8 + Tomcat combination are using Tomcat 8. Tomcat 8 also has Eclipse WTP support.

Comment: Does Tomcat v8 allow lambda-expressions in JSP websites? From what I read and heard it does not :/.

Comment: @Igor, I am almost sure it does, but you have to test it. I have not used Tomcat 8 with JSP at all.

Comment: This question is outdated by a fair bit.  Tomcat 9 is out and has been out for quite some time now.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get the adapters for Apache 9 by installing Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.9.4

[image]

Comment: Seems it was not possible back in 2015 :) Thanks for the update.

Comment: This works, make sure `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development ->  WST server adapters` is installed and bounce Eclipse after installing.

Answer (score 3):

Use a later version of eclipse e.g. Eclipse Neon.

It should work.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above methods but still was unable to find solution for the problem then I did the following and that helped me to add Apache tomcat to my Eclipse IDE:
After following **Help>Eclipse Marketplace** and installing **Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.10** still tomcat was not available so I went to **Help>Eclipse Marketplace>Installed>Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.10>Change** I put tick on the following and then I got the Apache Tomcat finally in my Eclipse IDE:

- JST Server Adapters
- JST Server Adapters Extensions
- JSF Tools-Tag Library Metadata(Apache Trindad)
- Git Integration for Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Use later **EE** version of Eclipse! Contains Tomcat adapters 8.5 and 9.0

I had same problem, but not now.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, eclipse marketplace was stucked on previous WST server adapters.
I've used old update feature `Windows > Install New Software`

In main update site, I found  `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development`   part, where **WST Adapters** where ready to update ...
[image: Eclipse update screenshot]
Eclipse MarketPlace often embed too much features & plugins.
On my own point view, easier to keep a light eclipse ;-)

*Tested on eclipse 2020-09*