# Apache Tomcat 9 Not Showing in Eclipse Server Runtime Environments

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have tomcat 9.0.11 installed, but the tomcat 9 server name does not see it to configure it , a solution please

[image]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this? Did Tomcat 9 exist when it was released?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded and installed tomcat 9 to your machine, then on Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environment, after clicking on Add, and then select your downloaded tomcat.

Comment: The poster is not asking how to add a Tomcat server. The question is why Tomcat 9 is not shown as a server type.

Comment: In Eclipse default installation all of the tomcat version doesn't view in the server runtime. For this reason, you should add tomcat server in runtime environment.

Comment: This is not answer for the question, I search found that tomcat supported by Eclipse 9 as well some where answered that follow Help>Eclipse Marketplace>Installed>Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.10 , but on Eclipse mars this version not shown in marketplace. Its better to move to eclipse neon for tomcat 9. You can follow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33910448/add-tomcat-9-to-eclipse

Answer (score 8):

Open your Eclipse IDE

Go to Help > Install New Software > Select a URL from where you want to install > Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development > select **JST Server Adapters Extensions** Next and Install.

It will install Apache Tomcat Adaptors. Then you will be able to see all the Tomcat Server Versions in your list.

Answer (score 4):

Right this issue popped up for me quite some time after the original post for a windows 10 x64 Eclipse 2020-09 for tomcat version 9. I went through the loops and the jumps to get to a final answer. For later versions you need the JST adapters mentioned above for the 2020-09 version of Eclipse that is located by going to:

Help -> Install new Software -> (in work with put in: https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/) -> (open drop down menu)Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development -> Select options :**JST Server Adapters, JST Server Adapters Extensions, JST Server UI** (the last one is for the event that the server ui isnt present which it wasnt on my version of eclipse)

in the event that you already have one of these installed it won't run an install on that particular one but run an update on it instead.

Comment: I used your instructions here and the Servers view now shows. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot

Comment: This worked for me. I also had to make sure the Eclipse Java plugin was current - updating the other plugins somehow caused the JST Server Adapters to no longer show Tomcat v9. Lombok was causing issues with the Java plugin, preventing updates (did not recognize customized Lombok configuration) but that is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a very old version of eclipse where the newer versions of servers aren't shown. Make sure you install the latest version (photon, or 4.8) of [the eclipse JEE package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/photon/r/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers) (or some other package with the WTP plugins) and you will see the latest supported server versions in that list.

Comment: This also happen in a 2022 Eclipse version, so the problem is not due to anolder Eclipse version

Answer (score 0):

You should install the latest Eclipse IDE.

It has worked for me:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkJuk.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE7Bt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to help and choose check for update. Then eclipse will updated to newer version which will show latest version of tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to change eclipse
Just take Update from Help -> Check for Updates
It worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34661949)